# Commutation rules of field operators and Dirac delta

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, eigenvalue, dirac-delta-distributions

My question concerns the commutation rules between bosonic fields operators in the case in which the bosons can assume only discrete positions.

I have organised this post in two sections, in the INTRODUCTION section I will explain the context in which the question arises, and in the QUESTION section the actual question and proposed solution.

INTRODUCTION:

From Landau, Lifshitz   Quantum mechanics. Non-relativistic theory [Vol.3. , 3ed] Pergamon  1991, par 64, Second quantisation

Given a discrete set of bosonic operators $\hat{a}_n$, satisfying the commutation relation
$[\hat{a}_n,\hat{a}^\dagger_{n'}]=\delta_{n,n'}$, the effect of $\hat{a}^\dagger_n$ is to create a boson in a state with wave function $\psi_n(x)$, e.g.
$$
|\phi>=a^\dagger_1a^\dagger_2|0,0,0,0,\dots>= a^\dagger_1a^\dagger_2|1,1,0,0,\dots>
$$
where $|\phi>$ is the Fock representation of the state having position symmetric wave function:
$$
\phi(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\psi_1(x)\psi_2(x)+\psi_2(x)\psi_1(x)\right)
$$

The field operator
$$
\hat\psi^\dagger(x)=\sum_n\psi_n^*(x)\hat{a}^\dagger_n
$$
increases by one the number of bosons in the system and satisfies the commutation relation
$$
[\hat\psi(x),\hat\psi^\dagger(x')]=\delta(x-x')\hspace{1cm}(1)
$$

QUESTION:

Let us consider the case where the bosonic single-particle wavefunctions are:
$$\psi_n(x)=\delta(x-X_n),$$ where $X_n$ is a discrete real variable that spans uniformly the interval $[-L/2,L/2]$ assuming $N$ different values.
Evaluating ${\rm Eq.}~(1)$  in this case yields
$$
[\hat\psi(x),\hat\psi^\dagger(x')]=\sum_{n'=1}^N\sum_{n=1}^N\delta(x-X_n)\delta(x'-X_{n'})\underbrace{[\hat{a}_n,\hat{a}^\dagger_{n'}]}_{\delta_{n,n'}} 
=\sum_{n}^N\delta(x-X_n)\delta(x'-X_{n}) \hspace{1cm}(1b)
$$

I have tried to evaluate Eq. $(1b)$ inside an integral as follows:
$$
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f({x}') \left(\sum_{n=1}^N\delta({x}-X_n)\delta({x'}-X_{n})\right) d x'=(*)
$$
performing the change of variable $x''={x'}-X_{n}$, and exchanging sum and integral we have
$$
 (*)=\sum_{n=1}^N\delta({x}-X_n)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f({x}''+X_n) \delta({x''}) dx'\\
 =\sum_{n=1}^Nf(X_n) \delta({x}-X_n)=\\ 
=f(x) \underbrace{\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \delta({x}-X_n)\right)}_{(**)}
$$
Now the term inside the parenthesis is intuitively independent from $x$.
One should show that the term $(**)$ is equal to 1 to prove that Eq. (1)=Eq. (1b).
Definins $\Delta X=L/N$, I have tried to estimate the term $(**)$ as follows:
$$
 (**)=\frac{1}{\Delta X}\sum_{n=1}^N \delta({x}-X_n)\Delta X\\
 \approx\frac{1}{\Delta X}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} \delta({x}-X)dX
 =\frac{1}{\Delta X}=\frac{N}{L}
$$

Since replacing the sum with the integral is rigorous only in the limit $N\to\infty$ so that $\frac{N}{L}$ is infinitesimal, it seems that Eq. (1) does not hold in the case in which one considers Dirac deltas as bosonic states.

I guess this problem is a quite general one in quantum field theory, and I ask if there is a way to prove that Eq. (1) is equivalent to Eq (1b), e.g. invoking renormalisation arguments.

I also guess that this problem is related to the fact that the eigenvalues of the position operator are continuous and thus one cannot pretend to satisfy the completeness relation of the basis using a discrete set of these eigenvalues. Is there any hypothesis which is missing from the introduction reported above and taken from Landau's book?